# Open aspx Page after WCF Callback

Tags: asp.net, wcf, callback, popup

I've the following problem:

I have to implemented a kind of a chat application. Therefore I use ASP.NET 4.5 and WCF. When I'm start click on the person I want to chat with, I call a wcf webservice. This webservice calls the wcf callback from the person I clicked on it. My problem is now, that I get the event called on the client side, but I am not able to open a new ChatWindow.

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class ChatContext : IChatClient, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Events

    public event EventHandler StartChat;

    #endregion


    public void FollowChatBegin(Person invitee)
    {
        StartChat(invitee, new EventArgs());
    }
```

I have registered the StartChat Event in my main page:

```
 public partial class MainPage: System.Web.UI.Page
{       

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // ...

        Global.ChatContext.StartChat += ChatContextOnStartChat;
    }

 private void ChatContextOnStartChat(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var person= (Person) sender;

        string path = this.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Remove(this.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf(Request.Url.LocalPath, Request.Url.LocalPath.Length));
        path += "/Controls/Chat/ChatWindow.aspx";

        string parameters = "did=" + person.Id + "height=700px,width=800px,resizeable=yes,status=no";
        path += parameters;

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "openChartWindow", "window.open('" + path + "');", true);

        this.upMain.Update();
    }
```

}

ChatContextOnStartChat gives me the following problems:

- this.Request is null
- I cannot call my UpdatePanel.Update

I have no idea how I can simply open a pop up / dialog whatever...  Can I just use a wrong pattern?